# If I keep JavaScript at bottom or keep JavaScript in <head> inside document.ready, are both same thing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, xhtml

If I keep JavaScript code at bottom or keep JavaScript code in `<head>` inside `document.ready`, are both same thing?

I'm confused between these two methodologies, http://api.jquery.com/ready/ and http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom.

Is there any benefit to putting JavaScript code at bottom (just before `</body>`) even if I keep the code inside.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       // code here
   });
```

As JavaScript is attached in

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 5):

In General, your should put your Javascript files at the bottom of your HTML file.

That is even more important if you're using "classical" `<script>` tag files. Most browsers (even modern ones) will block the `UI thread` and therefore the render process of your `HTML markup` while loading & executing javascript.

That in turn means, if you're loading a decent amount of Javascript at the top of your page, the user will expire a "slow" loading of your page, because he will see your whole markup **after** all your script has been loaded and executed.

To make this problem even worse, most browsers will **not** download javascript files in a parallel mode. If you have a something like this:

```
<script type="javascript" src="/path/file1.js"></script>
<script type="javascript" src="/path/file2.js"></script>
<script type="javascript" src="/path/file3.js"></script>
```

your browser will

- load file1.js
- execute file1.js
- load file2.js
- execute file2.js
- load file3.js
- execute file3.js

and while doing so, both the `UI thread` and the rendering process are blocked.

Some browsers like `Chrome` finally started to load script files in parallel mode which makes that whole problem a little bit less of an issue.

Another way to "workaround" that problem is to use `dynamic script tag insertion`. Which basically means you only load one javascript file over a `<script>` tag. This (loader) script then dynamically creates `<script>` tags and inserts them into your markup. That works asyncronously and is way better (in terms of performance).

Comment: So even my code is already inside document.ready , is it better to keep js at bottom?

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: definitely yes! Browsers will load & execute your complete script file, they can't distinguish javascript code -during- the load process. So it doesn't really matter if you wrap your code into jQuerys `.ready()` handler or not.

Comment: So if my js is already at bottom. then .ready() , will not make any difference.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: interesting point. Actually I would have to answer with "yes" - it should make no difference. The `.ready()` handler should fired instantly when executing a js file at the bottom of your markup. But then again I have second thoughts. Maybe you're loading huge image files in your HTML markup which take longer to load then your js files (those are loaded async by default). But in general, it should make no difference.

Answer (score 2):

They will load all the same in terms of you being able to access the code.

The differences are in the perceived speed of loading of the page. If the javascript is last it will not block any CSS that is trying to be downloaded, which should always be at the top, and will not block any images that need to be downloaded.

Browsers only ask for items as they find them in the HTML but they only have a limited amount of download streams (~10 in modern browsers) so if you doing a lot of requests for images/css and for JS something is going to lose and the perceived speed/ user experience of the page load of your page will take a hit.

Comment: Not only *perceived* speed - some old browsers that *just.won't.die* will drop into a different (less parallel) mode for downloading as soon as they encounter a `<script>` tag.

Comment: On the other hand, *if* the script is cached, the sooner it appears in the document, the sooner it will be able to start running. This is useless for access to DOM nodes which haven't loaded yet, but can be useful for other purposes, like (half-assed example because I'm tired) changing stylesheet rules for progressive enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same thing as the `ready` event is fired when the DOM tree has been built, while scripts at the end of the page may actually execute afterward.

Either way, they're both safe entry points for your app's execution.

Answer (score 1):

The Yahoo! Developer site is saying that if you put JavaScript at the bottom of the page, it won't block loading of other resources by the browser. This will make the page's initial load quicker.

jQuery is specifying a function to load when the entire page has loaded.

If you have a function which executes on page load, it won't matter whether you include it in `<head>` or at the bottom of the page, it will be executed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to consider what the JavaScript is actually doing on your page when deciding where to put it. In most cases, the time it takes to load and run JavaScript makes placing it at the end of the page more logical. However, if the page rendering itself depends on Ajax calls or similar, this might not be the case.

Here's a [good read](http://encosia.com/2010/08/18/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/) on the subject of `document.ready()` not being appropriate for all JS.

Answer (score 0):

Position of `<script>` tag don't involve your script if you use `document.ready`.
It seems JavaScript is charged faster when placed before `</body>` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Even with the script at the bottom of the HTML document, the DOM may not be fully loaded. All *closed* elements above the script will *typically* be ready, a DOM ready event may be necessary in corner cases.