# jQuery alert does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried for several hours know to make this bit of jquery code work but I just can't find what I did wrong with it. The equivalent in normal javascript works just fine. What is the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
      alert("HI");
      $(document).ready(function(e){
        alert("Hi");
        $("#button5").click(function(event)
        {
          alert("HI");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ezcap.css">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="sbheader"></div>
        <div id="button2"></div>
        <div id="button3"></div>
        <div id="button4"></div>
        <div id="button5"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="header">lol</div>
      <div id="footer">feg</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to make your titles a lot more descriptive with the actual problem. Also describe your desired outcome.

Comment: Script tag cannot contain script and source at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

You can't put a script in a  tag that has a src attribute. You need to call the jQuery library in one script tag and then put your actual script in another.

Try this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("HI");
  $(document).ready(function(e){
    alert("Hi");
    $("#button5").click(function(event)
    {
      alert("HI");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is here

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">

//js code

</script>
```

Here in your `script` tag you are giving a source and some code also, You should write separate `script` tags for both, see bellow

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
//js code

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script>
      alert("HI");
      $(document).ready(function(e){
        alert("Hi");
        $("#button5").click(function(event)
        {
          alert("HI");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ezcap.css">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="sbheader"></div>
        <div id="button2"></div>
        <div id="button3"></div>
        <div id="button4"></div>
        <div id="button5"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="header">lol</div>
      <div id="footer">feg</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the jQuery library while also implementing your code snippet here:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
```

You should be first loading the jQuery library and then implementing your code snippet like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  alert("HI");
  $(document).ready(function(e){
    alert("Hi");
    $("#button5").click(function(event){
      alert("HI");
    });
  });
</script>
```

The reasoning behind this is because you cannot call the script attribute to load a library and then define some code in the same tag, you need to:

1. Load the script
2. Declare your code

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The JS script reference line of code should end and actual JQuery code should be enclosed under separate script tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert("HI");
      $(document).ready(function(e){
        alert("Hi");
        $("#button5").click(function(event)
        {
          alert("HI");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ezcap.css">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="sbheader"></div>
        <div id="button2"></div>
        <div id="button3"></div>
        <div id="button4"></div>
        <div id="button5">abcd</div>
      </div>
      <div id="header">lol</div>
      <div id="footer">feg</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was including your code in that script tag for jQuery.

**Change to this:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ezcap.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="sbheader"></div>
        <div id="button2"></div>
        <div id="button3"></div>
        <div id="button4"></div>
        <div id="button5"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="header">lol</div>
      <div id="footer">feg</div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      alert("HI");
      $(document).ready(function(e){
        alert("Hi");
        $("#button5").click(function(event)
        {
          alert("HI");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Not a problem but you do not need the `type="text/javasript"`. See: [Do you need text/javascript specified in your <script> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265202/do-you-need-text-javascript-specified-in-your-script-tags)

And it is better to have your scripts at the bottom so that your content can load faster. See: [If I keep JavaScript at bottom or keep JavaScript in <head> inside document.ready, are both same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921727/if-i-keep-javascript-at-bottom-or-keep-javascript-in-head-inside-document-read)

Your `<link>` for CSS needed to be inside your `<head>`